# how to convert HttpPostedFile to thumbnail file. .net C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have been try to convert files to smaller file to insert database.

I try to covert images/HttpPostedFile to thumbnail file.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" OnClick="GenerateThumbnail" runat="server" Text="Generate Thumbnail" />
    <hr />
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Visible="false" />

</form>
```

and

```
protected void GenerateThumbnail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);
    using (System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            thumbnail.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[memoryStream.Length];
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)bytes.Length);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            Image2.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
            Image2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

public bool ThumbnailCallback()
{
    return false;
}
```

This part is causing error

```
HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);
```

how can I convert HttpPostedFile to thumbnail file?

Comment: It;s causing an error you say.... so... what's the error? And on which line?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't saved the file to disk so when you try to create the image from a file, it fails. Instead, create the image directly from the stream.

```
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream);
```

Comment: Image.FromStream(Stream) does not support .webp format.

Comment: @phiree Well, this answer was written in 2015, 3 years before Google released the first version. So yeah, of course it doesn't. The current [recommended action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action) is to use a third-party library.